# How to track down WPF NotSupportedException thrown by render thread?

Tags: .net, wpf, multithreading, render, notsupportedexception

I am working on a mixed-mode (C#,C++,C++/CLI) WPF application for which we get occasional crash reports from customers with a CLR System.NotSupportedException "No information was found about this pixel format" and a mixed callstack similar to (slightly shortened and  application methods renamed):

```
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat.CreatePixelFormatInfo() Zeile 468 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat.InternalBitsPerPixel.get() Zeile 494  C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.GetClosestDUCEFormat(System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat format, System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapPalette palette)    Unbekannt
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.DUCECompatiblePtr.get() Zeile 826    C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.UpdateBitmapSourceResource(System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel channel, bool skipOnChannelCheck) Zeile 713 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.UpdateResource(System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel channel, bool skipOnChannelCheck) Zeile 740 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.AddRefOnChannelCore(System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel channel) Zeile 140 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.IResource.AddRefOnChannel(System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel channel) Zeile 666 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.RenderData.System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.IResource.AddRefOnChannel(System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel channel) Zeile 869   C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RenderContent(System.Windows.Media.RenderContext ctx, bool isOnChannel) Zeile 5743    C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(System.Windows.Media.RenderContext ctx) Zeile 1243 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(System.Windows.Media.RenderContext ctx, System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.ResourceHandle handle) Zeile 1695 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(System.Windows.Media.RenderContext ctx) Zeile 1248 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(System.Windows.Media.RenderContext ctx, System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.ResourceHandle handle) Zeile 1695 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(System.Windows.Media.RenderContext ctx) Zeile 1248 C#
... lots of similar
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(System.Windows.Media.RenderContext ctx, System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.ResourceHandle handle) Zeile 1695 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(System.Windows.Media.RenderContext ctx) Zeile 1248 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.UpdateChildren(System.Windows.Media.RenderContext ctx, System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.ResourceHandle handle) Zeile 1695 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.RenderRecursive(System.Windows.Media.RenderContext ctx) Zeile 1248 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Visual.Render(System.Windows.Media.RenderContext ctx, uint childIndex) Zeile 1199 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.CompositionTarget.Compile(System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel channel) Zeile 68 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.CompositionTarget.System.Windows.Media.ICompositionTarget.Render(bool inResize, System.Windows.Media.Composition.DUCE.Channel channel) Zeile 181  C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Render(System.Windows.Media.ICompositionTarget resizedCompositionTarget) Zeile 866   C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandlerCore(object resizedCompositionTarget) Zeile 940  C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.RenderMessageHandler(object resizedCompositionTarget) Zeile 903  C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.MediaContext.Resize(System.Windows.Media.ICompositionTarget resizedCompositionTarget) Zeile 995   C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.OnResize() Zeile 629 C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndTarget.HandleMessage(MS.Internal.Interop.WindowMessage msg, System.IntPtr wparam, System.IntPtr lparam) Zeile 387   C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Interop.HwndSource.HwndTargetFilterMessage(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Zeile 511 C#
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Zeile 230   C#
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Zeile 121   C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) Zeile 85 C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Zeile 108   C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs) Zeile 767 C#
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) Zeile 222    C#
[Übergang von Systemeigen zu Verwaltet] 
[Übergang von Verwaltet zu Systemeigen] 
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DefWndProcWrapper(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) Zeile 106  C#
[Übergang von Systemeigen zu Verwaltet] 
[Übergang von Verwaltet zu Systemeigen] 
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) Zeile 235    C#
[Übergang von Systemeigen zu Verwaltet] 
[Übergang von Verwaltet zu Systemeigen] 
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherSynchronizationContext.Wait(System.IntPtr[] waitHandles, bool waitAll, int millisecondsTimeout) Zeile 74 C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.SynchronizationContext.InvokeWaitMethodHelper(System.Threading.SynchronizationContext syncContext, System.IntPtr[] waitHandles, bool waitAll, int millisecondsTimeout) Zeile 74   C#
[Übergang von Systemeigen zu Verwaltet] 
[Übergang von Verwaltet zu Systemeigen] 
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.InternalWaitOne(System.Runtime.InteropServices.SafeHandle waitableSafeHandle, long millisecondsTimeout, bool hasThreadAffinity, bool exitContext) Zeile 81 C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.WaitHandle.WaitOne(int millisecondsTimeout, bool exitContext) Unbekannt
System.dll!System.Net.FileWebRequest.GetResponse() Zeile 355    C#
PresentationCore.dll!MS.Internal.WpfWebRequestHelper.GetResponse(System.Net.WebRequest request) Zeile 154   C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.ColorContext.Initialize(System.Uri profileUri, bool isStandardProfileUriNotFromUser) Zeile 426    C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.ColorContext.ColorContext(System.Windows.Media.PixelFormat pixelFormat) Zeile 59  C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapImage.FinalizeCreation() Zeile 477  C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.CompleteDelayedCreation() Zeile 193  C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.Media.Imaging.BitmapSource.PixelWidth.get() Zeile 947   C#
[Übergang von Systemeigen zu Verwaltet] 
[Übergang von Verwaltet zu Systemeigen] 
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.GetValue(object item, int level) Zeile 397    C#
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue(int k) Zeile 773 C#
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.RawValue() Zeile 745  C#
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.RawValue() Zeile 368    C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(object newValue, bool isASubPropertyChange) Zeile 1346    C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ScheduleTransfer(bool isASubPropertyChange) Zeile 1241  C#
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.NewValueAvailable(bool dependencySourcesChanged, bool initialValue, bool isASubPropertyChange) Zeile 206    C#
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(int k, System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView collectionView, object newValue, bool isASubPropertyChange) Zeile 1210    C#
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.OnDependencyPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, bool isASubPropertyChange) Zeile 689 C#
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.OnSourceInvalidation(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, bool isASubPropertyChange) Zeile 294  C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.HandlePropertyInvalidation(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) Zeile 889 C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.OnPropertyInvalidation(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) Zeile 1030    C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.OnPropertyInvalidation(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) Zeile 1109    C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependentList.InvalidateDependents(System.Windows.DependencyObject source, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs sourceArgs) Zeile 68    C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) Zeile 815  C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType) Zeile 1558  C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, bool preserveCurrentValue) Zeile 709   C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.InvalidateDependents(System.Windows.Style ownerStyle, System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate, System.Windows.DependencyObject container, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, ref MS.Utility.FrugalStructList<System.Windows.ChildPropertyDependent> dependents, bool invalidateOnlyContainer) Zeile 1485 C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.StyleHelper.OnTriggerSourcePropertyInvalidated(System.Windows.Style ownerStyle, System.Windows.FrameworkTemplate frameworkTemplate, System.Windows.DependencyObject container, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs changedArgs, bool invalidateOnlyContainer, ref MS.Utility.FrugalStructList<MS.Utility.ItemStructMap<System.Windows.TriggerSourceRecord>> triggerSourceRecordFromChildIndex, ref MS.Utility.FrugalMap propertyTriggersWithActions, int sourceChildIndex) Zeile 1880  C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) Zeile 2810 C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) Zeile 798  C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType) Zeile 1558  C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValueCommon(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType, bool isInternal) Zeile 1368 C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.SetValue(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, object value) Zeile 1237 C#
MyButton.UpdateButton() Unbekannt
MyButton.OnAnyChange(System.Windows.DependencyObject d, System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e)    Unbekannt
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) Zeile 902    C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.FrameworkElement.OnPropertyChanged(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs e) Zeile 2782 C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.NotifyPropertyChange(System.Windows.DependencyPropertyChangedEventArgs args) Zeile 798  C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.UpdateEffectiveValue(System.Windows.EntryIndex entryIndex, System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, System.Windows.PropertyMetadata metadata, System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry oldEntry, ref System.Windows.EffectiveValueEntry newEntry, bool coerceWithDeferredReference, bool coerceWithCurrentValue, System.Windows.OperationType operationType) Zeile 1558  C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.DependencyObject.InvalidateProperty(System.Windows.DependencyProperty dp, bool preserveCurrentValue) Zeile 709   C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpressionBase.Invalidate(bool isASubPropertyChange) Zeile 821 C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.TransferValue(object newValue, bool isASubPropertyChange) Zeile 1462    C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Data.BindingExpression.ScheduleTransfer(bool isASubPropertyChange) Zeile 1241  C#
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.NewValueAvailable(bool dependencySourcesChanged, bool initialValue, bool isASubPropertyChange) Zeile 206    C#
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.UpdateSourceValueState(int k, System.ComponentModel.ICollectionView collectionView, object newValue, bool isASubPropertyChange) Zeile 1210    C#
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.ClrBindingWorker.OnSourcePropertyChanged(object o, string propName) Zeile 319    C#
PresentationFramework.dll!MS.Internal.Data.PropertyPathWorker.OnPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs e) Zeile 716  C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.WeakEventManager.ListenerList<System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs>.DeliverEvent(object sender, System.EventArgs e, System.Type managerType) Zeile 589 C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventManager.OnPropertyChanged(object sender, System.ComponentModel.PropertyChangedEventArgs args) Zeile 157   C#
MyDataModel.Something.set(int value)    Unbekannt
...
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.RoutedEventHandlerInfo.InvokeHandler(object target, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs routedEventArgs) Zeile 35    C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.EventRoute.InvokeHandlersImpl(object source, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args, bool reRaised) Zeile 181  C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEventImpl(System.Windows.DependencyObject sender, System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs args) Zeile 5435    C#
PresentationCore.dll!System.Windows.UIElement.RaiseEvent(System.Windows.RoutedEventArgs e) Zeile 5403   C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Controls.MenuItem.InvokeClickAfterRender(object arg) Zeile 357 C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) Zeile 85 C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Zeile 108   C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeImpl() Zeile 225 C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.InvokeInSecurityContext(object state) Zeile 238    C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Zeile 364 C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state, bool preserveSyncCtx) Zeile 337 C#
mscorlib.dll!System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(System.Threading.ExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Zeile 331   C#
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext.Run(MS.Internal.CulturePreservingExecutionContext executionContext, System.Threading.ContextCallback callback, object state) Zeile 96 C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherOperation.Invoke() Zeile 133 C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.ProcessQueue() Zeile 817    C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.WndProcHook(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Zeile 1260   C#
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndWrapper.WndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam, ref bool handled) Zeile 230   C#
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.DispatcherCallbackOperation(object o) Zeile 121   C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.InternalRealCall(System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs) Zeile 85 C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.ExceptionWrapper.TryCatchWhen(object source, System.Delegate callback, object args, int numArgs, System.Delegate catchHandler) Zeile 108   C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.LegacyInvokeImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherPriority priority, System.TimeSpan timeout, System.Delegate method, object args, int numArgs) Zeile 767 C#
WindowsBase.dll!MS.Win32.HwndSubclass.SubclassWndProc(System.IntPtr hwnd, int msg, System.IntPtr wParam, System.IntPtr lParam) Zeile 222    C#
[Übergang von Systemeigen zu Verwaltet] 
[Übergang von Verwaltet zu Systemeigen] 
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrameImpl(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) Zeile 922 C#
WindowsBase.dll!System.Windows.Threading.Dispatcher.PushFrame(System.Windows.Threading.DispatcherFrame frame) Zeile 908 C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.ShowHelper(object booleanBox) Zeile 2473    C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.Show() Zeile 2333   C#
PresentationFramework.dll!System.Windows.Window.ShowDialog() Zeile 2388 C#
MyApp.Main(string[] args)   Unbekannt
[Übergang von Systemeigen zu Verwaltet]
```

Unfortunately, we cannot reproduce this problem reliably but we have reproduced it occasionally. It seems to be very timing sensitive.

The problem occurs on various .NET 4 versions including recent ones from Windows 10 (e.g. clr.dll version 4.6.1073.0).

What makes me suspicious is that the same(!) BitmapSource instance appears twice on the callstack. The first call (BitmapSource.PixelWidth.get()) results in a wait operation during which a windows message is processed causing some render code to execute which finally causes further calls on the same BitmapSource instance.

Is this kind of re-entrancy really supported or might this be a bug in the .NET framework? The circumstance that some asynchronous message processing is involved would explain why it is so difficult to reproduce.

Any help greatly appreciated!